# Display a complete date into a Grid C#

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datagridview, grid

I have a Grid who display into a column a date except that the format of the date does not suit me.
Indeed, it only display the last two digits... off I wish I could see the last 4..

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP5jH.png)

Comment: Winforms or WPF? Tag please.

Comment: datagridview: You can set the CellStyle.Format.  Note: gridview != datagridview != grid - Always call things by their right name!

Comment: @Alexander Winforms ofc ;-)

Comment: @Taw Thx for the CellStyle.Format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Taw, i have done some research and here its how i could resolve my problem:

I just have add a variable:

```
string customFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Then:

```
        gridPrix.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = customFormat;
        gridPrix.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = customFormat;
```

Thx ;-)